# DNS: Access hosted servers tied to 3rd party domain instead of HOSTS

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, vpn, windows-server-2012, hosting

We are accessing some hosted servers (ex. dev1.hostco.tld, test1.hosted.tld, prod1.hosted.com, bakdev1.hosted.tld, baktest1.hosted.tld, bakprod1.hosted.tld)  across a VPN tunnel, that are tied to the hosting company's domain (ex. hosted.tld).

Currently we are using a HOSTS file to access these servers but I would like to move away from this and incorporate it into our internal DNS server. Problem is, When I added their domain and entries for the hosted servers into our DNS server, I can access the hosted servers as expected but all other traffic fails, such as to their website and email. All other traffic did not go out to the Internet and resolve.

How can I setup our DNS server to only forward the hosted servers across the VPN but let all others go out to the Internet?

Answer (score 0):

`How can I setup our DNS server to only forward the hosted servers across the VPN but let all others go out to the Internet?`

What you'll need to do is to add Conditional Forwarders on your DNS server that forward all queries for the `hosted.tld` domain to the name servers for `hosted.tld`.